# Windows 8.1 - Setting zoom levels via CSS

Tags: html, css, windows-8.1

So ever since I upgraded to 8.1, all of my sites have been showing up way zoomed in.  I was wondering if there was a CSS value I could set to always ensure the proper zoom level is set.  Thanks.

Comment: I have considered something similar. However, I don't think this is available without using javascript and some pixel to content size calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ***zoom*** property

```
body { zoom:0.9; -moz-transform: scale(0.9); }
```

As mentioned, Firefox doesn't support `zoom` so use `-moz-transform` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in FF.  FF doesn't support the zoom property.

Comment: So I actually tried that before, but for some reason, when I set the zoom scale to 1 in FF, it's the right size, but everything is pushed into the middle more.  Do you need to use that in conjunction with another attribute to make it look... normal?

Comment: Technically speaking, this works.  I decided it's an OS level setting and I don't want to do too much to override it.  If they want to be zoomed in, all other sites will be zoomed and look like crap.  Thanks.

Comment: @gabaum10 Sorry, I've only just seen this. There's no way to make it look normal, it's like when you use the browser to zoom in. It's a strange property and I'm not really sure what you could hope to achieve with it.